How to pass multiple contexts to a single function?
I'm creating a staking contract and one of the functions that takes in the deposits, I'm using a struct in the context of transferring SPL, however, to keep the records for the same I need to create another struct that I need to include in my context.
Can someone guide me on what the general approach is ?
Right now my code looks something like this :
use anchor_lang::prelude::*;
use anchor_spl::token::{self, Token, TokenAccount, Transfer as SplTransfer};

declare_id!("AVqeT4xHGScuSQj2rQq4gy35J4gR2zvc97aMJ6CHXsoG");

#[program]
pub mod stake {
    use super::*;

    pub fn stake(ctx: Context<TransferSpl>, amount: u128) -> Result<()> {
        Ok(())
    }
}

#[derive(Accounts)]
pub struct TransferSpl<'info> {
    #[account(mut)]
    pub from: Signer<'info>,

    #[account(mut)]
    pub from_ata: Account<'info, TokenAccount>,

    #[account(mut)]
    pub to_ata: Account<'info, TokenAccount>,

    pub token_program: Program<'info, Token>,
}

#[derive(Accounts)]
#[instruction()]
pub struct CreateReceipt<'info> {
    #[account(
        init_if_needed,
        payer = signer,
        space = 500,
        seeds = [],
        bump
    )]
    pub receipt: Account<'info, TransactionInfo>,

    #[account(mut)]
    pub signer: Signer<'info>,

    pub system_program: Program<'info, System>,
}

#[account]
pub struct TransactionInfo {
    pub user: Pubkey,
    pub balance: u128,
}


Hi what is the need to pass multiple context? you can pass everything in same context only, like varieties of PDAs, various programs, Accounts etc.
